# List mail transport rules of Admin using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API has support to retrieve mail rules for individual mail boxes. Is there any API to get the list of rules configured by Admin for the organization?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id/mailFolders/inbox/messagerules

Answer (score 0):

Not that i am aware of using Microsoft Graph API. At this point Graph API supports only individual mailboxes. The closest one i can see is that you can [application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to query other mailboxes as well. But it won't tell or get you the list of rules configured by admin for the organization. Being said that you can consider filing an uservoice so that it can be considered to be implemented. As an alternate you can use from Exchange PowerShell (something like [Get-Trasportrule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-transportrule?view=exchange-ps)).